# How to store social id in a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, facebook, indexing

I need to store some social ids (facebook/google/twitter user id, facebook place id, ecc..) in my MySQL DB. I found a lot of questions about this here on stackoverflow, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer. For example you can't be sure 100% that facebook id will always be a unsigned bigint, from facebook documentation the facebook id is described as "numeric string". Google id seems one digit bigger than bigint.

I believe that an index on a varchar column is slower than an index on a bigint column, for this reason I thought that using bigint, when possible, would be better than varchar. But I realized that you can store a varchar as a binary with the appropriate attribute.

For this reason I was thinking about use a varchar for all these social ids and (since the ordering is not an issue) store it as binary (attribute=binary), this because I need a fast index on them. 
what's your thoughts: is this a good and fast solution?
Thanks

Comment: A fast index? Are there slow indexes?

Comment: Well I believe that an index over a varchar column will be slower than on a int column, isn't it?

Comment: No not really. As long as you do it right, they're more or less the same. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `varchar`. You are right about the differences, but even more importantly, there is no guarantee that the current type will stay the same. For instance, Facebook changes the size in the past and they mentioned somewhere that they may include chars in it.

An index is an index, if done right, there is no need to worry about its performance. No real difference between an index on numbers or `varchar`.

Comment: Well this is a long topic, but it means creating indexes that your queries will use. For example, if you create an index on the `varchar` column, and issue a query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE 'abc%'`, then this query will not use the index and will run very slow. To solve it, you need to create an index on the first three characters only. But if you have another query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = 'xxxx'`, then you need a second index on the entire column. This also applies to number columns, but they are a bit easier to figure out.

Comment: I can confirm. I performed some benchmark myself: I can't see any difference between an index over a bigint or varchar.

Answer (score 1):

bigint + INDEX KEY + INNODB = Fast

Comment: I know, but it's not feasible when the social id is not a bigint

Comment: well a bigint unsigned uses 8 Bytes and max length is 18446744073709551615 if the facebook ids are major than a unsigned bigint then the only alternative is to use a CHAR (if you know the length) OR a varchar  and use MyISAM engine with ROW_FORMAT=FIXED the another huge improvement is to create 9 to store the fb ids. if a facebook id start with 2 SELECT will go to table 2 if another facebook id start with 6 go to table 6 this is to distribute the ids and not to use a single table for all facebook ids.

Comment: check this post to see the speed or ROW_FORMAT=FIXED: http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2012/09/mysql-optimization-faster-selects-myisam-fixed-row-format